Не получается скачать numpy в Pydroid3 | csin
Пытаюсь скачать, но все проблема та же. Я уже пробовал: переустановить, очистить кэш, скачать с аргументами, но все равно — не получается.
Ошибка:

Checking for function "csin" with dependency -lm: NO


Вы ставили через pip или через встроенный менеджер пакетов?
